# How to show this blog django backend by its id in react frontend

Tags: reactjs, django

models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

serializers

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'
```

views

```
class BlogDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
```

and urls

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

I'm trying to make a blog website. How can we show blogs by id in react js

Comment: how does your react code loom like? did you write something? If not maybe you should follow a tutorial and come back when you have the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get list of blogs ordering by id. So, you can do like this-

views -

```
class BlogDetailView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-id') # descending order 
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
```

Comment: i've created backend and got blogs by id in BlogDetailView but now want to show them in react js